# How to understand "c'est l'affaire de tous"?

Tags: expressions, sens, vocabulaire

Specifically, what is the meaning of *affaire* in this sentence?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would aim at “It is everybody's business”.

*Affaire* in this context means “stuff one should be interested in”, it is not related to commercial activities (unlike, for instance, in *homme d'affaires*, which means *businessman*)

Comment: Some variants : *It is everybody's concern / matter*

Answer (score 6):

*Affaire* generally corresponds to “business” in the sense of something that somebody should be concerned about (the kind of business that one minds).

> *C'est l'affaire de tous* = “it's everybody's business”. The phrase is a bit more idiomatic in French, it might be translated as “this is a public concern”.
>   *Occupe-toi de tes affaires* = “mind your own business”
>   *J'en fais mon affaire* = “I'm making this my business”, “I'm taking care of this”

*Affaire* is broader than “business” in this meaning, it can more generally mean something that is happening and is a concern of some kind.

> *La mystérieuse Affaire de Styles* = “The Mysterious Affair at Styles”
>   *L'affaire Dreyfus* = “the Dreyfus Affair” (and *affaire* would generally be used in this sense in French even where English would use “case”)
>   *C'est une affaire d'argent, de cœur, d'État...* = “it's a matter of money, of love, of State…”

The word *affaire* has many other meanings, including some other meanings which can be translated as “business” in the economic sense:

> *Les affaires marchent bien cette année* = “business is booming this year”
>   *Il a monté une affaire* (rare, one would usually use *entreprise* or (colloquial) *boîte*) = “he started a business”, “he started a company”
>   *Le monde des affaires* = “the business world”